# Parameterized PUT operation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, crud, put

I'm building a simple angularJS app using CRUD operations combined with a REST API. I have 3 tables in my database (User,Role,Project). 'Role' is an association table between 'User' and 'Project'.  I would like to modify a row in the 'Role' table and I wonder if there is any possibility for making a put request with parameters like PUT(http://host/api/Role?userId=x&projectId=z,theDataToBeInserted).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you send the parameters as part of the request body? Note that insertions should be done with POST, not PUT.

Comment: Pass userId and projectId as url parameters, but pass the DataToBeInserted as request Json/Xml payload. Advanced tip:- Avoid using PUT and use POST instead(even for update) as some servers of organisations block PUT and DELETE methods. Why do u want to expose your DataToBeinserted in Url params?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've tried your solutions but I got the same error. In the response from the server, the URL parameters are set to null

Comment: EDIT : The error code is 23502. According to Postrgres docs, it is a not null violation. That's pretty weird because the parameters are absolutely not null